# How to have the same position of the background image in the css background

Tags: css

As you can see from the code, I would like to have the same position of my image in the same place as my gradient. Why? The background image is noise in webp. For the sake of page weight, the noise image is small and repeated in css to simply import a really light image. But suddenly it's a nightmare for the noise to align perfectly with my gradient (superimposed)

```css
div {
  width: 800px;
  height: 800px;
  background-size: initial;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILZHP.png);
  background-color: #ffab00;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

```css
div {
  width: 800px;
  height: 800px;
  background-size: initial;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg,#ffab00 50%,transparent 100%),linear-gradient(270deg,white 0%,transparent 9%,transparent),url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILZHP.png);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: I've converted your sample to a snippet which I *think* demonstrates your issue. Please continue to edit it if not. Can you also explain in more detail what is incorrect about your sample code, perhaps with more sample code which shows a correct version? I don't really know what it means for "noise to align perfectly with gradient".

Comment: Outside the gradient there should no longer be any noise image. So we must have an all white background on the left. Is that clearer ? But impossible to do it on my side

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit tricky to suggest something because "outside the gradient" is not a clear area of this image. The whole thing is the gradient, even the transparency which allows the noise to show through, so its already true that no noise is outside of the gradient.

I assume you mean "outside the orange part", but that could be anywhere along the transition from orange to transparent. A gradient is not a clearly defined object.

One thing you could do is add a hard stop and fill in the rest of the image with white. This creates a hard edge, but leaves the most noise intact:

```css
div {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-size: initial;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-image: 
    linear-gradient(260deg, #ffab00 10%, transparent 46%, white 46%),
    url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILZHP.png);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Or you could add yet another linear-gradient underneath and play around with the values until you get something suitable:

```css
div {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-size: initial;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-image: 
    linear-gradient(260deg, #ffab00 10%, transparent 46%), 
    linear-gradient(260deg, transparent, transparent 36%, white 46%),
    url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILZHP.png) !important;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

The key value in this example is `transparent 36%`. Decreasing this percentage will show *less* defined noise, as the white bleeds into that section of the image for longer.

Here is an example with a radial-gradient:

```css
div {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-size: initial;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-image: 
     radial-gradient(circle at top right, #ffab00, transparent 20%),
     radial-gradient(circle at top right, transparent, transparent 10%, white 20%),
     url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILZHP.png);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Sorry, but how you can do with a radial gradient ? Im bad and i cant do the same thing. (        background-image: radial-gradient(circle at bottom right,#ffab00 0%,transparent 20%),radial-gradient(circle at top left,#fff 89%,transparent 94%),url() !important;

Comment: @bobibobboby see the edit. I realised that having the second layer reversed is unnecessarily confusing, and basically cannot be used for radial-gradient since circles won't tessellate.

Comment: Thanks again. However, why can't I see the noise on the full color? I edited my code to see the difference. Thanks.